# How to create an inner border of a donut pie chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a donut pie chart progress bar. 
I want to give them an inner border, I've tried

```
.pie{

  box-sizing:border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
  width:70px;
  height:70px;
  border:2px solid black;
  border-radius:50%;

}
```

I want my pie chart to look like this :

[image]

I keep getting this as my result :

[image]

Here is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gu3aL84e/3/).

Comment: Does this help? http://jsfiddle.net/gu3aL84e/4/

Comment: @HashemQolami : Your approach is good, but it leave a small **slightly** outer border, I don't think I want that. Can you adjust your Fiddle to get rid of that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that easyPieChart is offseted with the border, since the chart is drawn using a `canvas`.

You can however use `box-shadow` instead, replace the `border` line with:

```
box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 11px black;
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 11px black;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 11px black;
```

That should do the trick for you.

By the way, the CSS `width` and `height` are being overridden to `110,110` and not `70,70`

---

**EDIT:**

Here is the working code for the inner border WITHOUT the outer hardly seen outer border:
HTML:

```
<div class="pie" data-percent="90" >
    <span>6</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.pie {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0 10px black;
    border-radius:50%;
}

.pie canvas {
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    left: -1px;
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.pie').easyPieChart({
    barColor: '#62ae41',
    scaleColor: false,
    lineWidth: 10,
    trackWidth: 10,
    animate: false,
    lineCap: 'square',
    size: 110
});
$('.pie').css('width', '108px');
$('.pie').css('height', '108px');
$('.pie').css('line-height', '108px');
```

and voila, the pie chart of dreams.

all in one [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tbc1230/a4vkqozv/2/)

---

**Explanation:**

For the most part, this is the same as your fiddle, what changed was:

- the size of pie chart is added to the options
- the canvas is *shifted* to hide the outer border,
- the original div size is decreased so all the shadow-box sets inside the generated canvas.

And that's it.

PS: I hate it when I have to change the style of generated code, but I HAD TO play with the generated `canvas`

Comment: I test it again this morning. Your approach is very close, but it leave a small slightly outer border, I don't think I want that. Can you fix it and update your answer ?

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome. May I ask why 11 px ? Just curious. Thanks.

Comment: in your fiddle, your `easyPieChart` `lineWidth: 10` i simply added 1 pixel

Comment: Make sense. Thanks. Any idea with the outer border ?

Comment: I'm trying that right now, will update the answer when finished

Comment: @rangerover.js I updated the answer, hope this fixes your problem :)

Comment: You got it. I also see your Fiddle. May I ask, why do we need :    $('.pie').css('width', '108px');
    $('.pie').css('height', '108px');
    $('.pie').css('line-height', '108px'); -- Can I set these settings somewhere else, Imagine I have 100 pie charts, I am afraid that my code will look a little tedious. Don't you think ?

Comment: Quoting _the original div size is decreased so all the shadow-box sets inside the generated canvas_, otherwise the shadow will extend below and left of the pie, and no you can't use CSS, since easyPieChart is adding those to the element style directly.

Comment: So those 3 lines must be there ? and there is nothing we can do, unless, I decide to move out of easy-piechat.js. Right ?

Comment: will no, I think you're missing the pint of CSS selectors here, you don't have to write those lines for EVERY pie chart, you simple add an empty CSS class per size `.pie110 {} .pie70{}` and then `$('pie110').css(...)`, and if all the pie charts has the same size, then you only have three lines

Answer (score 2):

It's not perfect but you can play with the top, left, width, bottom values, just add:

```
.easyPieChart *::before {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 50%;
    bottom: 9px;
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    left: 8px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    width: 83%;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gu3aL84e/6/

Comment: It does in the link I provided, can you provide with a link that doesnt?